# Product of copies of a matrix and its transpose.

Tags: matrices, nonnegative-matrices, positive-matrices

Let $M$ be a square (entrywise) [nonnegative matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix), and suppose that $M^n$ is (entrywise) [positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Positive_matrix) for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider now a product of $n$ matrices such that each of the matrices appearing in the product is either $M$ or the transpose of $M$. Is the product (entrywise) [positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Positive_matrix)? If not, is it always possible to find an $n'$ for which the product of $n'$ factors as above is always (entrywise) [positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Positive_matrix)?

Answer (score 1):

I played around with it a bit after misreading your question. If you take

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 1 & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 1 \\
       1 & 1 & 1 \\
      \end{pmatrix}$$

then $M^2$ is positive in all entries but if you take $M\cdot M^T$ it is not. Not sure if that's what you have in mind but if I didn't misread your question again that answers it in the negative.

Edit to answer the comment:

Take $M=\begin{pmatrix}
       0 & 1 & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & 1 \\
       1 & 0 & 0 \\
      \end{pmatrix}$.

Then $M^5$ is entrywise positive but $M\cdot M^T\cdot M^3$ has zeros and so has $M\cdot M^T\cdot M^2,M\cdot M^T\cdot M,M\cdot M^T$.

Comment: What about $M^T M$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Well $M^T\cdot M$ is entrywise positive but since his question was if you can always find a $n'$ for any such product and not if there is a product that works I think that's a counterexample, isn't it?

Comment: That works --- thank you very much! Do you think it is also possible to find a counterexample such that the diagonal is zero (in other words, in a way that $M$ is the adjacency matrix of a loopless digraph)?

Comment: @GaussJordan Edited with a counterexample you where asking for.

Comment: @MaikPickl I was thinking in terms of "given matrix $\bf M$, is there an $n \geq 2$ such that..."

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Puh, that's a different question and I suspect in this case the answer is positive but I can't prove it now.